# Nesting Masonry objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, graph, jquery-masonry

I am trying to create a graph view using containers. So if: [A's -> B's -> C's] the view would show an objects c inside of Bs which are inside of As.

Something like this:
[image]

I think a masonry view is perfect for this but I can't get the nesting to work right.

Fiddle of what I have so far: http://jsfiddle.net/paulocoelho/5SxQ5/4/

I don't get why they are not alining. I also tried using CSS's column-count and column-gap but found the rendering to be extremely buggy.

Fiddle code coz I must...

```
var $container = $('.container');
$container.masonry({
    /*columnWidth: 200,*/
    itemSelector: '.eWrapper'
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider this.

Remove `itemSelector` property - if the one is set `Masonry` will use not only children items but all descendants that match that selector. So, for the first container (`motherContainer`) `Masonry` would try to layout ALL `.wrapper` elements, include those in nested `.container` elements.

And the key point - call `Masonry` on the reverted array of `.container` elements. From the innermost to the outermost, because Masonry changes children elements' height leaving gaps in the parent container.

```
var $container = $('.container');
$($container.get().reverse()).masonry({});
```

Just give it a try. Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5SxQ5/7/).
I also added C elements.