# Nested Isotope layouts possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-isotope

I'm trying to use the Isotope layout library to create a visualization of a number of "houses" (represented by boxes) that each can contain a number of "rooms" (represented by a different colour of boxes).  Each room contains a list of person names - some rooms have few names, some have more.

In HTML it looks like this:

```
<div class="houses">
  <div class="house">
    House A
    <div class="room">Room A<ul><li>Name 1</li><li>Name 2</li></ul></div> 
    <div class="room">Room B ...</div>
    <div class="room">...</div>
  </div>
  <div class="house">
    House B
    ...
  </div>
  ...
</div>
```

I'm then trying to use Isotope twice to get this nested effect:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.house').isotope({
    itemSelector: '.room',
    layoutMode: 'masonry',
  });

  $('.houses').isotope({
    itemSelector: '.house',
    layoutMode: 'masonry',
  });
});
```

The CSS looks like this:

```
  .room { border: 1px solid black; padding: 4px; margin: 5px; background-color: blue }
  .house { padding: 5px; margin: 5px; background-color: red; }
  .houses { padding: 5px; margin: 5px; }
```

However it is not working - the "houses" collapse and are show as small boxes in the top left corner. The "rooms" are shown as very narrow boxes seemingly randomly laid out on the page, most of them on top of each other (overlapping) in the top of the page.

If I add a fixed width to .house, for example "width: 30%" - everythings looks great. I then get 3 columns of "houses", with "rooms" neatly layout within.

However it is not what I'm looking for, as sometimes 30% of the page is too large a box, and sometimes it is too little. Especially when the page is supposed to be responsive, it is quite a problem.

How can I get the "outer" Isotope instance to respect the widths calculated by the "inner" Isotope instance?

Have I missed an easier way of doing this? - or do I need to look at a different layout library?

I have created a jsfiddle that shows the problem here:

http://jsfiddle.net/Gt8qn/

When you uncomment "width: 30%;" - the boxes layout properly as nested boxes.

Comment: can you provide a fiddle? you will probably have to declare that the child is also an isotope. I don't see the reason why it will not work.

Comment: I'll create a fiddle! - How do you declare that the child is also an isotope? - I have searched through the options without finding such as possibility?

Comment: May be **[THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18392884/nesting-masonry-objects)** will help.

Comment: @vico I have added the fiddle to the question now - I hope you can help!

Comment: ok let me try this again

Comment: can i ask how you decide what the WIDTH will be then? by how many *rooms in a house?

Comment: I would like the width of the "house" to be determined by the width of the "rooms". If the inner Isotope determines that a "house" will contain 3 columns of "rooms" that each are 30px - then the total width of the house should be 90px (+ padding). Note that I do not want every "house" to be the same width! So for another "house", the inner Isotope could have decided that there's only 1 column of "rooms" that are each 50px width. Then that house should only be 50px + padding in width.